# Monaca Backend doesn't find target devices for push notifications

Tags: cordova, notifications, push, backend, monaca

Monaca Push Notification Backend management returns error dialog:

> An error occurred while registering the push queue: There are no target devices

when I try to send push notification. I've tried only with an android device and Monaca Debugger.

Device is connected to IDE and the app works perfectly.

Comment: is it the Google Play version debugger or a custom debugger?

Comment: Monaca Debugger in Google Play

Comment: please open a ticket [here](https://monaca.mobi/en/support/technical)

Comment: I have a basic plan and can't request technical support

Comment: then, please open a ticket [here](https://monaca.mobi/en/support/inquiry)

Comment: Hi! I am facing similar problem. Did you find solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notification support for Monaca Debugger was deprecated almost one year ago. At the moment it's possible to send push notifications just to apps physically installed on the device. You should not have any issue doing that.